# Update Json value in json Array in Java

Tags: java, json

```
{
  "page": {
    "size": 2,
    "number": 2
  },
  "places": [
    {
      "eventName": "XYZ",
      "createdByUser": "xyz@xyz.com",
      "modifiedDateTime": "2021-03-31T09:59:48.616Z",
      "modifiedByUser": "xyz@xyz.com"
    }   
   ]}
```

I am trying to update the "eventName" field with new String. I tried with the following code, It updates the field but returns only four fields in the json array.

```
    public String modifyJson() throws Exception{
    String jsonString =  PiplineJson.payload(PiplineJson.filePath());
    System.out.println(jsonString);
    JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    String uu = jobject.getJSONArray("places")
                       .getJSONObject(0)
                       .put("eventName", randomString())
                       .toString();
    System.out.println(uu);
    return uu; 
}
```

This is what the above code does.

```
{
  "eventName": "ABCD",
  "createdByUser": "xyz@xyz.com",
  "modifiedDateTime": "2021-03-31T09:59:48.616Z",
  "modifiedByUser": "xyz@xyz.com"
}
```

I am trying to get the complete json once it updates the eventName filed.

```
{
  "page": {
    "size": 2,
    "number": 2
  },
  "places": [
    {
      "eventName": "ABCD",
      "createdByUser": "xyz@xyz.com",
      "modifiedDateTime": "2021-03-31T09:59:48.616Z",
      "modifiedByUser": "xyz@xyz.com"
    }   
   ]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way that you are chaining the operations together.  The problem is that you are calling `toString()` on the result of the `put` call.  The `put` calls returns the *inner* JSONObject that it was called on.  So you end up serializing the wrong object.

Changing this:

```
String uu = jobject.getJSONArray("places")
                   .getJSONObject(0)
                   .put("eventName", randomString())
                   .toString();
```

to

```
jobject.getJSONArray("places")
       .getJSONObject(0)
       .put("eventName", randomString());
String uu = jobject.toString();
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are returning the first element you extracted from "places" array. You should return "jobject.toString()" instead.